# bitbake fetcher failure when building Digi Embedded Yocto

Tags: fetch, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build Digi Embedded Yocto using the instructions found [here](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/embedded/dey/4.0/cc8x/yocto-create-build-projects_t.html#build-images). It uses a Docker container, so the process seems straight-forward (i.e. I didn't have to install anything in the container), but I'm getting the following error when I run `bitbake dey-image-qt`.

ERROR: linux-dey-5.15-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/usr/local/dey-4.0/sources/poky/scripts:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-dey-linux-gnueabi:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/usr/local/dey-4.0/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/dey"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat clone --bare --mirror https://github.com/digi-embedded/linux.git /home/dey/workspace/downloads/git2/github.com.digi-embedded.linux.git --progress failed with exit code 128, no output
ERROR: linux-dey-5.15-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'git://github.com/digi-embedded/linux.git;protocol=https;branch=v5.15/stm/dey-4.0/maint')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/dey/workspace/ccmp15-dvk/tmp/work/ccmp15_dvk-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-dey/5.15-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.43254
ERROR: Task (/usr/local/dey-4.0/sources/meta-digi/meta-digi-arm/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-dey_5.15.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

I expected this to work out of the box since I haven't made any modifications. I can clone github.com/digi-embedded/linux.git and checkout the stated branch v5.15/stm/dey-4.0/maint, so the url and source seem ok. I tried this on both a Linux host machine and a faster Windows host machine (the results were the same as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the following (from the error message)

`git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat clone --bare --mirror https://github.com/digi-embedded/linux.git /home/dey/workspace/downloads/git2/github.com.digi- embedded.linux.git`

and then `bitmake dey-image-qt` worked. So that’s a work-around.